# Disable beep in git diff on windows

Tags: windows, git

While paging through the results of executing `git diff`,  I hear annoying beep sound when I get to the end or beginning of the diff results.  I would like to know how I can disable this alarm bell?

I am running msysGit on Windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not tell what you are paging with but let me guess it is `less`, and that is less that actually produces the bell. You can start less with the `--quiet` or `--silent` options to avoid (or sett the `LESS` environmental variable).

Answer (score 19):

You can turn off that annoying beep for all Windows apps using:

```
net stop beep
```

Comment: To disable it permamently go to the device manager-> view-> show hidden devices and in "Non-Plug and Play Drivers" disable the Beep.

Answer (score 8):

By default, msysGit uses `less` as the pager when running `diff`s.  In order to disable `less`' bell sound, the command line option -q needs to be supplied to it.  This can be accomplished by modifying the `git` configuration for your user account or the project.  Add the following to the configuration file:

```
[core]
    pager = less -q
```

The location of your user accounts git configuration file is ~/.gitconfig.  In Windows speak, that is `%userprofile%/.gitconfig`.

*-- Anwser provided by the OP, Mario*

Comment: `git config --global core.pager 'less -q'`